# js/php with include files

Tags: javascript, php, css

this is my code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>EVENTI</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/stile.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Squada+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> <!--importare google font-->
<script src="../JS/ridimensionapagina.js"></script>
<script src="../JS/jquery-1.11.1.js.js"></script>



</head>
```

in my "ridimesionapagina.js" i've some JS code that debunk some of my elements declared in my css code , but in this page it doesen't works why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQuery in ridimensionapagina.js, you should put .. include jQuery path to above to load jQuery before loading ridimensionapagina.js file

Answer (score 2):

Well making the assumption that you're using jQuery in your `ridimensionapagina.js` file, one would assume you'd fix the issue by reversing the order you load the scripts so that jQuery is in fact available when your `ridimensionapagina.js` script loads and runs.

```
<script src="../JS/jquery-1.11.1.js.js"></script>
<script src="../JS/ridimensionapagina.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="../JS/ridimensionapagina.js"></script>
<script src="../JS/jquery-1.11.1.js.js"></script>
```